# UIMenuController is not Visible on UILongGestureRecognizer

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, uigesturerecognizer, gesture

I referred various post on SO for the same issue. But still not able to get the solution.

I have **sub-Class** the `UIButton` where I am having `UILongGestureRecognizer`. My Implementation goes as below:

```
- (id)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame
{
    self = [super initWithFrame:frame];
    if (self) {
        UILongPressGestureRecognizer *longGesture = [[UILongPressGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(longPress:)];
        [self addGestureRecognizer:longGesture];
    }
    return self;
}

- (BOOL)becomeFirstResponder
{
    return YES;
}

- (BOOL)canPerformAction:(SEL)action withSender:(id)sender
{
    return YES;
}

- (BOOL)canBecomeFirstResponder
{
    return YES;
}

- (void)longPress:(UILongPressGestureRecognizer *)gesture
{
    if (gesture.state == UIGestureRecognizerStateBegan)
    {
        NSLog(@"ButtonView: longPress: event called");
        UIMenuController *menu = [UIMenuController sharedMenuController];
        if (![menu isMenuVisible])
        {
            ButtonView *btn = (ButtonView *)gesture.view;
            if (![btn becomeFirstResponder])
            {
                NSLog(@"couldn't become first responder");
                return;
            }

            UIMenuItem *menuItem = [[UIMenuItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"Change Color" action:@selector(changeColor:)];
            UIMenuController *menuCont = [UIMenuController sharedMenuController];
            menuCont.arrowDirection = UIMenuControllerArrowDown;
            menuCont.menuItems = [NSArray arrayWithObject:menuItem];
            if([btn canBecomeFirstResponder])
            {
                [menuCont setTargetRect:btn.frame inView:btn.superview];
                [menuCont setMenuVisible:YES animated:YES];
                NSLog(@"menu visible....");
            }
        }
    }
    if (gesture.state == UIGestureRecognizerStateEnded || gesture.state == UIGestureRecognizerStateCancelled || gesture.state == UIGestureRecognizerStateFailed)
    {
        [self.layer setBorderColor:[UIColor clearColor].CGColor];
        [self.layer setBorderWidth:0.0];
    }
}
```

I have override `becomeFirstResponder` and `canBecomeFirstResponder`.

**Important to Note:** My Log message **"menu visible...."** is getting logged when I long pressed the Button, But I am not able to see the UIMenuController visible.

Is there anything that I am still missing in above code?? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add this line before showing the menu:

```
[self becomeFirstResponder];
```

And remove this code:

```
- (BOOL)becomeFirstResponder
{
    return YES;
}
```

Comment: Absolutely... Great.... Thanks thank a lot.... +1. But still I dont understand that though I have already added `[self becomeFirstResponder];` this line, then why my UIMenuController was not visible?? Also, I have implemented `- (BOOL)becomeFirstResponder` to return YES, then why would this not working as expected??  Above all accepting your answer.. thanks once again.

Comment: you can override `canBecomeFirstResponder` to update state or perform some action such as highlighting the selection - but then you still need to call the super-class implementation.

Comment: @DShah the menu controller was not visible because in your method override you did not call `[super becomeFirstResponder]` – it actually did not do anything but reporting "yup, i've added myself to the responder chain and made myself the first responder